Rule exclusions on google cloud armor not working for ARG_NAMES
Im setting up WAF functionality on a gke LB using cloud-armor, and i managed to get the security-policy working as expected, except for one thing: im using auth0 for authentication, and when the user comes back from the login, there is a cookie set which triggers a false positive. So im trying to define a exclusion for this:

Im testing with a curl like this:
curl 'https://....' -H 'Cookie: _gcl_au=1.1.1234434153.1725007007;'

which returns 200, if i append a auth0 header like this:
curl 'https://....' -H 'Cookie: _gcl_au=1.1.1234434153.1725007007; _com.auth0.auth.Xv4.1ZaAOBMBmrIV~q.cv9Qj3Nx0HLcU_compat={%22nonce%22:%22OUUDejiw5uoISci04gjbtPODOydZTbTH%22%2C%22state%22:%22Xv4.1ZaAOBMBmrIV~q.cv9Qj3Nx0HLcU%22};'

Then the request is still dropped, though it should be allowed due to the exclusion rules in my understanding. Anyone has an idea how to fix/debug?
UPDATE
The cookie-exception somehow works now, i dont know what changed. But now i have the same problem with a URI exclusion:

When i fire
curl 'https://<snip>/my-post-url' -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer <snip>'n --data-raw '<snip>'
<!doctype html><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>502</title>502 Bad Gateway

The logs show this:
previewSecurityPolicy: {
 configuredAction: "DENY"
 inspectedBodySize: 604
 matchedFieldLength: 604
 matchedFieldType: "ARG_NAMES"
 matchedFieldValue: ","message_defini"
 matchedLength: 41
 matchedOffset: 68
 name: "<snip>"
 outcome: "DENY"
 preconfiguredExprIds: [
  0: "owasp-crs-v030301-id942200-sqli"
 ]
 priority: 1
}

Im not sure, but maybe its a more general problem with cloud armor: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/319400527?pli=1 But "dont run this rule on URI xy" seems like a very very basic configuration, so maybe im still missing something?

Hm, apparently the problem solved itself somehow. I will wait a day if it happens again, otherwise i will nevermind-and-close this

Could you please confirm whether this issue has been resolved? If not I am happy to assist you.

While the problem on the cookies somehow disappeared, i now have the same problem with a URI exclusion. Let me know what kind of details i can provide for further debugging

Could you kindly provide additional details regarding the problem, such as the specifics of the URI exclusion you are experiencing?

I already updated the problem description, If there is Info missing, please let me know

Enable logging to see if the requests with the URI in question  are hitting the exclusion or being blocked by another rule.Because these logs can help you identify which rules are applied an in what order.

Also when testing with curl ,ensure you are including the full URI. For example: curl 'https://yourdomain.com/path/to/excluded/resource'

Please dont spam SF with chatgpt answers.
